# AngularJS with bootstrap 3 accordion not working when included via ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, accordion, angularjs-directive, twitter-bootstrap-3

The problem is the following: As soon as I use the accordion in a view that is loaded in the ng-view directive, the accordion title clicks dont work correctly anymore

http://plnkr.co/edit/KGwuqDIb7I5NrYCtPOPk?p=preview

If the accordion is use in the page itself with no ng-view, the accordion works perfectly

http://plnkr.co/edit/8dY7JU1kxjZ2jAKmMIrP?p=preview

Any clue to what Im missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that Bootstrap appends `#according_name` within a `a` tag. This triggers a AngularJS routing and due to route change `test.html` is loaded again on every click on accordian link.

Your options are to try to configure `$locationProvider` to use HTML5 mode with hashbag if it works

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
```

See some documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

Other would be to use [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) component but it has been not ported to support version 3 of bootstrap.

Comment: Hey, I changed the .html5Mode to false and now it works! thanks :)

Comment: Looks like the documentation that you added is no longer available. Could you add another link?

Comment: @CodedContainer please check now.

Answer (score 40):

Actually, there might be a simpler solution.

You can just make sure that the links don't propagate the URL change.

Add to the `a` tag `onclick="return false;"`

Comment: This worked for me. It might not be the best practice but I've been stuck with this for a few hours now. Thanks @mfloryan!

Comment: You just solved what I've been struggling on for hours. Thank you! Good catch.

Comment: That's called solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 15):

You can empty the `href=""` and use

`data-target="#collapse"` instead, this worked for me

i.e

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="" 
data-target="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
```

Comment: +10 if a could. This should be the accepted answer! Non-intrusive in general app config as `html5Mode` and a good practice using the same attribute for others similar components

Comment: After trying lots of things, this was the solution for me!

Comment: +1 This helped me a lot, I was getting weird behavior with my accordion even after switching into html5 mode (and rewriting my expressJS urls) -- adding `data-target` and emptying my `href` remedied all the odd accordion behavior -- thank you greatly!

Answer (score 1):

I was having an issue using href and data-target together, so if you are using this in an application I'd recommend specifying one or the other but not both.

When I used both, I'd get redirected to my login page as soon as I clicked on it.  With one or the other specified it worked fine, but not with both.